# Magento 1.9.2.3 Customer Password Reset return "Your password reset link has expired"

Tags: magento1.9.2.3, forgot-password

Forgot Your Password Not working at the customer end, how to solve this error? If click **Reset Password** from Email returns **Your password reset link has expired.**

Comment: Can you share more detail regarding this.

Comment: Customer use forget password, the reset link will send to customer mail , if click reset password  link from mail then it shows : Your password reset link has expired.

Comment: Can you share you code when you click on that link which controller it hits.

Comment: dis you recently patch your Magento store ?